# Connected and path-connected subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology

Question: Find all connected and path-connected subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$

We've shown that the connected subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ are all sets that contain exactly one element of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now our reasoning is as follows: Since path-connected subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ are connected as well, all path-connected subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ are only the single-element subsets as well.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: That was quick. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.$                        $